# PHP date adding in DateTime object does not work

Tags: php, datetime

Try to do:

```
$datetime = new DateTime();
$onehour = new DateInterval('PT1H');
$datetime->add($onehour);
$timestamp = $datetime->date;

echo $timestamp; // nothing
```

What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 2):

There's no such `date` property in the DateTime object.

Instead you can use `format()` to get the date formatted according to given format.

```
echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

or use `getTimestamp()` to get the Unix timestamp:

```
echo $datetime->getTimestamp();
```

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php

Answer (score 0):

You have to use :

```
DateInterval::createFromDateString("1 hours");
```

Instead of :

```
new DateInterval('PT1H');
```

As Given Below Code :

```
$onehour = DateInterval::createFromDateString("1 hours");
$date = new DateTime();
$date->add($onehour);
echo $date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```